# Why do the max values of long and long long produce the same output?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14, c++builder

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <climits>

int main () {

    int n_int = INT_MAX;
    short n_short = SHRT_MAX;
    long n_long = LONG_MAX;
    long long n_llong = LLONG_MAX;

    cout << "int is " << sizeof (int) << " bytes." << endl;
    cout << "short is " << sizeof n_short << " bytes." << endl;
    cout << "long is " << sizeof n_long << " bytes." << endl;
    cout << "long long is " << sizeof n_llong << " bytes." << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Maximum values:" << endl;
    cout << "int:   " << n_int << endl;
    cout << "short: " << n_short << endl;
    cout << "long:  " << n_long << endl;
    cout << "llong: " << n_llong << endl << endl;
    //cout << endl;

    cout << "Minimum int value = " << INT_MIN << endl;
    cout << "Maximum int value = " << INT_MAX << endl;
    cout << "Bits per byte = " << CHAR_BIT << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**
The long and long long variables are producing the exact same maximum values, I'm not sure why. The long value is supposed to output the maximum value of 2147483647.

```
int is 4 bytes.
short is 2 bytes.
long is 8 bytes.
long long is 8 bytes.
Maximum values:
int:   2147483647
short: 32767
long:  9223372036854775807
llong: 9223372036854775807
Minimum int value = -2147483648
Maximum int value = 2147483647
Bits per byte = 8
```

Answer (score 9):

`long` is not guaranteed to be 32 bits long; it merely has to be *at least* 32 bits long. Your implementation has defined `long` to have 64 bits. Note that even though `long` and `long long` have the same range on your implementation, they are nevertheless distinct types.

Comment: Longs are NOT required to be at least 32 bits.  The only builtin type with a guaranteed size is a char, and sizeof(char) will always be 1.  And this does not mean 1 byte.  It means 1 unit (of whatever a char is on that machine.)  The only guarantee is that longs are AT LEAST AS LARGE as ints, and long longs are AT LEAST AS LARGE as longs.

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis Sorry, you're wrong about that. The C standard says that `LONG_MAX` must be at least 2147483647 and `LONG_MIN` must be at most -2147483647. This requirement is incorporated into the C++ standard by reference. This implies that `long` is at least 32 bits.

Comment: Since we're talking C++ here, I am correct.  From the C++ standard 8.3.3: "sizeof(signed char) and sizeof(unsigned char) are 1. The result of sizeof applied to any other fundamental type (6.9.1) is implementation-defined."  Further, from 21.3.5: "The header <climits> defines all macros the same as the C standard library header <limits.h>. [ Note: The types of the constants defined by macros in <climits> are not required to match the types to which the macros refer."

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis The fact that the result of `sizeof` is implementation-defined does not nullify the requirement that `long` must be able to represent every value from -2147483647 to +2147483647. Mathematically, this implies that it is at least 32 bits long. The note you quoted is completely irrelevant.

Comment: [\[basic.fundamental\]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.fundamental#3.sentence-6). This is one of the few places in the C++ core language that explicitly incorporated the C standard by reference.

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis -- `sizeof(char)` is **one byte**. That's "byte" **as defined in** the C++ standard. It doesn't necessarily mean "8 bits"; a byte must be **at least** 8 bits.

Comment: The question is tagged for both Visual C++ and C++Builder.  Note that both of them implement `long` as 4 bytes on Windows. However,  Cygwin implements `long` as 8 bytes on Windows. And `long` can be 8 bytes on other platforms, too (iOS 64bit, for example). So, if portability is an issue, use standardized fixed-length types, like the `LONG` and `LONGLONG` macros on Windows (always 32 and 64 bits, respectively), `int32_t` and `int64_t` (always 32 and 64 bits, respectively), etc.